# Problem with consistency on Scylla (Cassandra)

Tags: database, cassandra, consistency, scylla

Please help me with the following problem:

There is a Scylla cluster (5 nodes). Kafka messages are processed in the application. Scylla stores entity by сomposite partition key (externalId, systemId).
When processing a Kafka message, Scylla stores the entity processing data, after processing the entity goes to the next stage of processing in another microservice.

After processing, a notification is received for this entity
At this stage a floating problem appears: an entity with outdated data is received from Scylla

[image]

What we tried to do:

- Executed request (1) as a lightweight transaction
- Write consistency_level = ALL in the scylla driver (spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra is used).
  These actions did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the ScyllaDB (and Cassandra) consistency model, you control the *consistency level* of the write and the read separately. If you want to be sure that after an update completed, a select will read the updated data, you need to pick certain combinations of write and read consistency levels that will allow that. For example writing with QUORUM (when RF=3, this means 2 out of 3) and then reading again with QUORUM, ensures that the read reaches at least one up-to-date node so you read the up-to-date data.

That being said, writing with consistency level ALL - which you said you tried - should have also been enough, no matter which consistency-level is used for read: In CL=ALL writes, the write waits until every single replica was successfully updated. At that point, a read to any node will return the updated data - there is no node left with outdated data to return!
So if CL=ALL didn't work for you, my guess is that something in your application is wrong. For example, maybe one of the following happend:

1. You thought you set CL=ALL on writes in your application code, but it had no effect.
2. Some writes failed and you didn't notice. A CL=ALL write that **fails** doesn't guarantee consistency of what it wrote.